Intermittent Error on Spark Snowflake Library Communication Error: HTTP Status 503
I am using the Spark Snowflake library to load data from Snowflake into a Spark DataFrame, but sometimes I encounter a communication error. So, this is an intermittent error, sometimes it happened and other times it's just running fine.
The job is scheduled over airflow 2.6.3.
The error message I receive is:
Error in data fetch: An error occurred while calling o47.load.\n: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: HTTP status=503.\n\tat 

Spark Version: 3.3.4
Snowflake Spark Connector Version: spark-snowflake_2.13-2.13.0-spark_3.3
Snowflake JDBC: snowflake-jdbc-3.15.1.jar
Here's how i generate the snowflake configuration
            snowflake_spark_conf = {
                "sfURL": self.config.snowflake.url,
                "sfUser": self.config.snowflake.user,
                "pem_private_key": certificate,
                "sfDatabase": self.config.snowflake.database,
                "sfSchema": self.config.snowflake.schema,
                "sfWarehouse": self.config.snowflake.warehouse,
                "sfRole": self.config.snowflake.role,
            }

            self.df = (
                self._spark_session()
                .read.format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake")
                .options(**snowflake_spark_conf)
                .option("query", query)
                .load()

Has anyone else encountered this HTTP 503 error when using the Spark Snowflake library? What could be causing this issue, and how can I address it?
Thank you for your help!
I haven't tried anything to resolve this, it's not always happened

Seems pretty obvious there is some overload on the snowlfake db. My uneducated guess is that messing around with the number of partitions could help here? If you have 200 partitions all trying to load data from snowflake it will overload the server, so reducing it will mean less concurrent requests potentially

There's not a whole lot you can do. A 503 means the service is unavailable. Snowflake at the backend can scale up or down depending on the load. During that period, it's expected to reply to clients with a 503.
If this occurs frequently enough for you to be considered disruptive, then I recommend you contact Snowflake Support to have it looked into.
You could also ask the JDBC driver to retry HTTP requests for a little longer by passing the maxHttpRetries parameter and setting it to something higher than the default value of 7.

I solved this by upgrading the spark-snowflake_2.13-2.16.0-spark_3.3.jar
It turns out that the version that i used previously set the retry to 0, and it's being fixed on the version 2.16.0
